# не могу определить причину зацикливания в перцептроне

Tags: java, нейронные-сети

Код перцептрона

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.regex.Match;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Perceptron {
Reader rd = new Reader();
double[][] patterns;
double[] answers;
double[] enters;
double[] hidden;
double outer;
double[][] wEH;
double[] wHO;

Perceptron(double[][] patterns, double[] answers) throws IOException {

    this.patterns = patterns;
    this.answers = answers;
    enters = new double[patterns[0].length];
    hidden = new double[3];
    wEH = new double[enters.length][hidden.length];
    wHO = new double[hidden.length];

    initWeights();
    study();


    double[][] input = {{-43, -45}};
    for (int p = 0; p < input.length; p++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++)
            enters[i] = input[p][i];

        countOuter();


        if (outer == 1) {

            System.out.println("Точка принадлежит прямой");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Точка не принадлежит прямой");
        }

    }

}

public void initWeights() {
    for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < wEH.length; j++) {
            wEH[i][j] = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wHO.length; i++)
        wHO[i] = Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.1;
}

public void countOuter() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        hidden[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < enters.length; j++) {
            hidden[i] += enters[j] * wEH[j][i];
        }
      hidden[i]= Math.round(1 /(1+ Math.exp(-  hidden[i])));

    }
    outer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        outer += hidden[i] * wHO[i];
    }
    outer = 1 /(1+ Math.exp(-outer));
}

public void study() {
    double[] err = new double[hidden.length];
    double gError = 0;
    do {
        gError = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < patterns.length; p++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++)
                enters[i] = patterns[p][i];

            countOuter();

            double lErr = answers[p] - outer;
            gError += Math.abs(lErr);

            for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
                err[i] = lErr * wHO[i];
            for (int i = 0; i < enters.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < hidden.length; j++) {
                    wEH[i][j] += 0.1 * err[j] * enters[i];

                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++)
                wHO[i] += 0.1 * lErr * hidden[i];
        }  System.out.println("GError: " + gError);
    } while (gError != 0);

}

}
```

Класс Main

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    double[][] patterns = {{-23.0,17.0},{-19.0,-34.0},{-42.0,-3.0},
            {-43.0,34.0},{-45.0,-21.0},{41.0,-14.0},{27.0,-18.0},{19.0,34.0},{-34.0,-18.0},{-4.0,-26.0},{32.0,-23.0},{-2.0,-36.0},{37.0,-22.0},{27.0,47.0},{-1.0,38.0},{32.0,-48.0},{-36.0,-36.0},{0.0,-48.0},{9.0,-50.0},{27.0,15.0},{27.0,20.0},{5.0,-30.0},{18.0,9.0},{45.0,14.0},{49.0,-26.0},{-42.0,27.0},{-1.0,38.0},{0.0,7.0},{45.0,18.0},{-17.0,-50.0},{20.0,48.0},{27.0,24.0},{-31.0,-36.0},{41.0,28.0}};
    System.out.println(patterns.length);

    double[] answers = {0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0};



    Perceptron p = new Perceptron(patterns,answers);


}
}
```

В перцептроне ищу причину. попробовал вывести глобальную ошибку он ее бесконечно выводит. По чему то зацикливается

Comment: у Вас в цикле do/while gError никогда не будет равен 0 отсюда и бесконечный цикл

Comment: Если я поменяю условие ,  он перестает обучается и выдает всегда отрицательный результат

Comment: Тогда ставьте условие выхода из цикла, if (передельный показатель ошибки = такой-то) showStats(); break;

Comment: Для чего это необходимо?showStats(); break; ?

Comment: showStat() - как пример вывода информации в консоль какой хотите break; - выход из цикла